# Is it correct to have a for on a label and a aria-labelledby on a select tag?

Tags: accessibility

For context the issue I have is that in NVDA and JAWS screenreaders, then user selects an option in a dropdown, it doesn't announce the selection. So I thought that perhaps this would solve the issue. Unfortunately, I'm unable to test it since I don't have a Windows computer.

I was wondering if changing this:

```
<label for="select-id" > Some Label </label>
<select  id="select-id"> 
   <option>  </option</>. (empty option on purpose to have nothing selected)
   <option> A </option</>
   <option> B </option</>
</select>
```

To this, will solve my issue.

```
<label for="select-id" id="label-id"> Some Label </label>
<select  id="select-id" aria-labelledby="label-id"> 
   <option>  </option</>. (empty option on purpose to have nothing selected)
   <option> A </option</>
   <option> B </option</>
</select>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it will make no difference, the association is already there with the `for="idOfElement"`.

As for announcing the selection then only thing that I can see from the HTML given is that you don't have a `value` on the `<option>` (well and the options are the same but I am assuming that is purely for the example). It shouldn't make a difference but as I have never created a `<select>` without using `value` attributes on the options that is the only thing I can see / think of.

For Clarity (as it isn't entirely clear what behaviour you are describing) it will not announce when you select an item, as that should already have been announced when you cycled through the options.

Expected Behaviour:

- focus the select "option 1 selected label announced" should be read
- press down arrow "option 2" will be read
- press "enter" there will be no announcement.

Comment: This is an amazing explanation Graham. it does get announced, but when I hit enter there is no announcement. Is this the expected behavior then?

Comment: I also have one option that's completely empty, just updated code above to reflect it, would that make any difference?

Comment: The empty option will not announce anything, perhaps swap that out for "choose..." or similar. Everything else should stay the same though (announcing the control etc.) And yes, pressing "Enter" to select an option is not expected to announce anything (I am sure you can change the verbosity settings in a screen reader to allow it to announce selections but not by default). Glad it helped!

Comment: Thank you so much Graham, this was really helpful :)